# C# SmtpServer "The operation has timed out"

Tags: c#, winforms, smtpclient

I have problem in sending mail by smtp and gmail in C# winform application.
without attachment sending is successfully but when attachment is added application was thrown to System.Net.Mail.SmtpException and it's message is "The operation has timed out."
what's the problem?!

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        Attachment att=new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("Path");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        smtpClient.Timeout = 20000;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        (from@gmail.com, "password"  );


        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress from = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from@gmail.com,
            from,
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("to@gmail.com");



        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = "some text";
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = "Subject";
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Bcc.Add(bcc@gmail.com);



        message.Attachments.Add(att);

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // The operation has timed out
        }
```

> Edit

i have this problem both of gmail and yahoo!

Comment: The attachment is too large and it fails to upload within the given timeout. Either increase/disable the timeout or choose a smaller attachment to upload until it works.

Comment: @GentiSaliu my attachment file is 984kb and disabled timeout but i get that error again!

Comment: You have tried without an attachment?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes and mail sent successfully

Comment: Probably the SMTP server has a timeout option as well. Try sending a smaller attachment, say 1KB. Also check that you don't have some firewall/antivirus blocking the connection after a while.

Comment: OK, Just noticed it in your question. So try a tiny text file with a letter

Comment: you sure the path of the file is correct?

Comment: @GentiSaliu in file that less than 300kb mail sent , but i want to send file max to 15MB. what's your solution? before i can send a few day ago but now i can't!

Comment: Do you have a different gmail account that you can test with? This smells like it could be throttling by gmail. If the other account works with a large file, then you have root cause, but have a different problem to solve (not code).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any major flaw in your code and I think `GMail` raised its attachment size limit to `50Mb` some time ago... anyway, I suggest you to proceed with the following modifications:

1. Increase your timeout as much as possible, this alone could solve your problem if you are dealing with very big attachments: `smtpClient.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue;`.
2. Try to use different server port. Maybe you have other applications (`Outlook`, for example) using the port `25` to communicate and this creates a conflict. Switch to `465`. If it doesn't work, try with `587`.
3. Try to make a test using a different account.

Comment: Your 2nd approach was my solution for 3rd party mail server, changing port 465 to 587 resolved the problem. Oddly,when using CDO mail object, the port 465 was working without any issue. Edit: Maybe CDO was blocking SMTP 465 as well? I can not say. Both were client applications. Anyway, thanks!